# Access attribute of child of a child using python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

xml file:

```
<Protocol1 channel="AljazeeraHD"> 

<frame source="vd01" id="4">

</frame>
<frame id="18" source="vd01">
   <rectangle id="1" height="87" width="976" y="889" x="414"/>   
</frame>
<frame id="23" source="vd01">
   <rectangle id="1" x="300" y="886" width="1095" height="89"/>   
</frame>
<frame id="35" source="vd01">
   <rectangle id="1" x="316" y="53" width="242" height="34"/>   
   <rectangle id="2" x="635" y="886" width="755" height="90"/>
</frame>
</Protocol1>
```

Want to access value of attribute 'x' from rectangle.

Code to convert xml_to _csv:

```
def xml_to_csv(path):

xml_list = []
for xml_file in glob.glob(path):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for member in root.findall('frame'):
        frameNo = root.attrib['channel']+'_'+member.attrib['source']+'_frame_'+member.attrib['id']
        #print(member.find('rectangle').attrib['x'])
        #print(member.getchildren().attrib['x'])
        #print(member.find('rectangle').attrib['x'])
        value = (frameNo,
                 1920,
                 1080,
                 'Artificial',
                 int(member.find('rectangle').attrib['x']),                    
                 )
        xml_list.append(value)
print(glob.glob(path))
column_name = ['FrameNo', 'imgwidth', 'imgheight',
               'class','X']
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
print(xml_list)        
return xml_df
```

Where 'member= frame' in a loop.

1.

```
member.getchildren().attrib['x']
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

2.

```
member.find('rectangle').attrib['x']
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Right now, it is not clear what packages/modules you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ElementTree and assuming your code looks like this:

```
members = """
<doc>
   <frame id="18" source="vd01">
      <rectangle id="1" height="87" width="976" y="889" x="414"/>
   </frame>
   <frame id="19" source="vd01">
      <rectangle id="1" height="87" width="976" y="889" x="333"/>
   </frame>
</doc>
"""
```

Then this should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(members)
for frame in doc.findall('.//frame'):         
       print(frame.attrib['x'])
```

Output:

```
414
333
```

EDIT:

Following your change to the xml, change the `for`loop to:

```
for frame in doc.findall('.//frame[rectangle]'):    
      for rec in frame.findall('.//rectangle'):
         print(rec.attrib['x'])
```

Now the output should be:

```
414
300
316
635
```

Comment: It gives <Element 'rectangle' at 0x7f6f326af530> till member.find('rectangle') but when we add member.find('rectangle').attrib['x'] it says AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'.

Comment: @maryammehboob Then please edit your question and add a short, representative sample of the html you're working with.

Comment: JackFleeting, Thank you so much edited answer worked for me. I was missing inner for loop.